# Failed to properly install Rtools in windows10

Tags: r, rtools

I was trying to install `Rtools` in `Windows-10` machine and was following the directions in https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

But after following all steps mentioned there I got message -

```
> Sys.which("make")
make 
  ""
```

Below is my system info -

```
> Sys.info()
       sysname        release        version       nodename        machine          login           user effective_user 
     "Windows"       "10 x64"  "build 17763"      "XXX"       "x86-64"
```

Can you please help to understand what went wrong?

Comment: Did you follow all steps; 1. download and run executable at default settings (so you now see a directory at C:\\rtools40),  2. within R run `writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")` . Did you do this at R terminal or in an IDE?

Comment: Yes, I already did it with `R`